# How can I execute a callback after a set of asynchronous service calls complete?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

In Flex, I'm making a set of asynchronous calls:

```
service.method1.send().addResponder(responder1);
service.method2.send().addResponder(responder2);
service.method3.send().addResponder(responder3);
```

I want to execute some code after *all* of these service calls have returned (either success or failure, I don't care which). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Implement a [CallResponder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/CallResponder.html) that will monitor the results from each responder & increment a variable in the listener after each result. When the variable hits three, execute some code.